# Array populated by .each() returns correct IN .each(), but loses data after

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, key-value

I have the following snippet getting distance values for an origin post code from an auto-generated list of available destination postal codes.

The code to obtain the distances works correctly.

I can, within the `.each()` actually see exactly what I want which is an array of `postcode: distance` key/value pairs.  So that does exactly what I want.

Where things fall apart is that after the `.each()` loop has run, and I check the array I've populated during it, all I get is the list of postal codes and the distance values appear to have been dropped.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY">
</script>
jQuery( document ).ready( function() {
        var distance_array = {};
        jQuery( '#postal_search_btn' ).on( 'click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var postalorigin = jQuery( '#postal_search' ).val();
            var postals_string = jQuery( '#available_postals' ).attr( 'data-postals' );
            var postals_array = postals_string.split( ',' );
            jQuery( postals_array ).each( function( i, nextpostal ) {
                var serviceDM = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
                serviceDM.getDistanceMatrix( {
                    origins: [postalorigin],
                    destinations: [nextpostal],
                    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
                    avoidHighways: false,
                    avoidTolls: false,
                }, callbackDM );
                function callbackDM( response, status ) {
                    if( status == google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK ) {
                        var origins = response.originAddresses;
                        var destinations = response.destinationAddresses;
                        var rows = response.rows;
                        distance_array[nextpostal] = rows[0].elements[0].distance['value'];
                        console.log( distance_array );
                        return distance_array;
                    } else {
                        console.log( 'error' );
                    }
                }
            } ).promise().done( function( distance_array ) {
                console.log( distance_array );
            } );
        } );
    } );
```

As you can see above I `console.log( distance_array )` inside the `callbackDM()` function that runs within the `.each()` and when I do that I get the following:

`{N4K 1N4: 142995, L4Z 1R9: 20144, L0S 1B8: 124377, M5V 1V6: 49608, L6S 4H1: 7662}`

However, when I `console.log( distance_array )` AFTER the `.each()` I get this:

`["M5V 1V6", "L4Z 1R9", "L6S 4H1", "N4K 1N4", "L0S 1B8"]`

So what I want is for the key/value pair to be available to me outside of the `.each()` loop and the `callbackDM()`, I then want to sort the pairs based on the distance, from lowest to highest, and then trim the array to the 3 closest (smallest) distances.
I can't do any of that right now because I don't have the distances in the array outside the `.each()`.

What I do then is use the three postal codes with the smallest distances and use AJAX to run a query against the WP DB to find locations with matching postal codes, but I have that part covered. (And there will be matching postal codes because the first list of potential destinations is generated based on what is actually available.)

Note:  I looked into the asynchronous aspect as expected and one of the proposed solutions is to use `.promise()` and `.done()` which are being used.  The final variable check is synchronously running after the `.each()`.  Additionally, both the postal code and the distance value are added at the same time during the `callbackDM()` function, so as soon as one is present, the other should be as well.  The `distance_array` variable is empty.

Comment: top JS duplicate of all times: [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)

Comment: Not really, because it is being altered.  The `distance_array` variable is actually completely empty.  Both the postal codes and the distances are being added in the loop by the callback.

Comment: `var distance_array = {}; `     ¯\\_ಠ_ಠ_/¯

Comment: jQuery's [`jQuery.each`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/#jQuery-each-array-callback) on an array returns void/undefined, so the fact that you are calling `.promise()` on its return value tells me there is more going on here than what is being said in the question.

Comment: `postals_array` is generated by running a `split( ',' )` on a comma-separated string. I'm running the `.each()` on that.

Comment: Indeed. I am able to follow the code fine. I'm just telling you (and linking to) the documentation for the `jQuery.each` function does not return anything that has a `.promise()` method on it. I don't know why yours does. Perhaps you are using a library or plugin that adds that functionality which you have not mentioned in your question?

Comment: Just so you know, the typical way of doing this would be to `map` the `postals_array` to an array of promises, then use `Promise.all` (or `jQuery.when`) to collect the results of those promises into one array, perhaps `map`ping for `flat`tening that array to get the data you need.

Comment: Other than WP's default jQuery and the Google maps API, there's nothing else.  If I strip `.promise()` out and use just `.done()` I then get an `undefined` message.  I didn't include the maps API because it has the API Key.  I'll edit the question.

Comment: $.each is synchronous. So, anything you put below that block will run after the $.each completes. It doesn't return a promise. Definitely  heed Herectic Monkey's advice, and for the love of all things holy, do not name your variable `distance_array` when it's an object literal.

Comment: Thanks @BenTheHumanMan, all of this is just working code and will be renamed and cleared up once I get the actual key/value list I need returned.